# Node/Express Cannot POST error (React frontend) while uploading image

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs, express

I am new to Node.JS, I am trying to run a MERN movie ticket booking system. The following code snippet in the front end represents the function for uploading an image for a particular movie:

```js
export const uploadMovieImage = (id, image) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', image);
      const url = '/movies/photo/' + id;
      console.log(url);
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data
    });
      console.log(response);
      const responseData = await response.json();
      console.log(responseData);
    if (response.ok) {
      dispatch(setAlert('Image Uploaded', 'success', 5000));
    }
      if (responseData.error) {
          console.log("error 2");
      dispatch(setAlert(responseData.error.message, 'error', 5000));
    }
  } catch (error) {
      console.log("error");
 
    dispatch(setAlert(error.message, 'error', 5000));
  }
};
```

This is my index.js in the server side:

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  require('dotenv').config({ path: path.join(__dirname, '../.env') });
}

require('./db/mongoose');

// Routes
const userRouter = require('./routes/users');
const movieRouter = require('./routes/movies');
const cinemaRouter = require('./routes/cinema');
const showtimeRouter = require('./routes/showtime');
const reservationRouter = require('./routes/reservation');
const invitationsRouter = require('./routes/invitations');

const app = express();
app.disable('x-powered-by');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// Serve static files from the React app
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../../client/build')));
app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../uploads')));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  // Website you wish to allow to connect
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

  // Request methods you wish to allow
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

  // Request headers you wish to allow
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers,X-Access-Token,XKey,Authorization'
  );

  //  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

  // Pass to next layer of middleware
  next();
});
app.use(express.json());
app.use(userRouter);
app.use(movieRouter);
app.use(cinemaRouter);
app.use(showtimeRouter);
app.use(reservationRouter);
app.use(invitationsRouter);

 //app.get('/api/test', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World'))

// The "catchall" handler: for any request that doesn't
// match one above, send back React's index.html file.
//app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '../../../client/build/index.html'));
});
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`app is running in PORT: ${port}`));
```

Below is the code snippet for the router ./routes/movies

```js
// Create a movie
router.post('/movies', auth.enhance, async (req, res) => {
  const movie = new Movie(req.body);
  try {
    await movie.save();
    res.status(201).send(movie);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).send(e);
  }
});

router.get(
  '/movies/photo/:id',
  auth.enhance,
  upload('movies').single('file'),
  async (req, res, next) => {
      const url = `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}`;
      console.log(url);
    const { file } = req;
    const movieId = req.params.id;
    try {
      if (!file) {
        const error = new Error('Please upload a file');
        error.httpStatusCode = 400;
        return next(error);
      }
      const movie = await Movie.findById(movieId);
      if (!movie) return res.sendStatus(404);
      movie.image = `${url}/${file.path}`;
      await movie.save();
      res.send({ movie, file });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      res.sendStatus(400).send(e);
    }
  }
);
```

The image fails to get uploaded and when I run inspect/console, it shows [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0UOs.png)

Comment: Why should it be able to POST? The code you've shown us has `app.get('/*'` but there's no sign of any post handler. Maybe it is in one of the routers you haven't shown us. Please provide a [mcve] - the code you've provided is neither minimal nor is it enough to reproduce the problem. Don't use the live demo feature if it is going to error because the code isn't designed to run in a browser.

Comment: Regardless, this has to be the cleanest code I've ever seen from someone who's "new to Node.js"

Comment: I have included the post handler. Please take a look at the edited question @Quentin

Comment: @KarthikaMenon i still don't see a post handler at the route you're posting to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making a POST request to `/movies/photo/someId`

Your POST handler is for `/movies`, not `/movies/photo/:id`.

You need to make your URLs match!